# How can I use PhantomJS to convert a DIV to a PDF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, phantomjs

I have been reading other answers here who suggest that PhantomJS is the best library to use to convert HTML to PDF while preserving CSS etc. in the PDF, that many other libraries have issues doing.

I looked at their website but I couldn't see the method to convert a specific DIV to PDF.

For example everything between `<div id="pdfContent">` and `</div>` needs to be converted to a PDF.

Can someone provide a simple example?

Comment: This doesn't answer the direct question, but I would like to add that another great tool for converting html to pdf is one from google called "wkhtmltopdf". This is actually a utility that would be installed on the hosting server (if possible) but then is VERY flexible and easy to use, with perfect results for me for years.

Comment: AFAIK phantom by itself won't let you do this. You can do it for `iframe`s, but not divs. You may have limited success filtering the page's content using regex, but more likely a separate HTML parser would be needed (and that will probably cause additional problems with styling)